# Add dictionary to sortedDict

Tags: python, django, dictionary, sorteddictionary

I have an array of dates/objects in a dictionary:

```
task_list[d] = [tasks, pick]
```

where d is a date, tasks is a list of objects, and pick is an integer

I have another dictionary for overdue objects:

```
overdue_list={}
overdue_list['Overdue Tasks'] = [overdue_actions, 0]
```

If I added the overdue_actions to the task_list and sorted:

```
task_list['Overdue Tasks'] = [overdue_actions, 0]
total_task_list = SortedDict( sorted( task_list.items() ) )
```

I'd get all of the dictionary keys in chronological order followed by "Overdue Task".  But I actually want to list "Overdue Task" first, followed by the dates in chronological order.

Is there a way for me to add the following two dictionaries together into a SortedDict?

```
overdue_list['Overdue Tasks'] = [overdue_actions, 0]
task_list = SortedDict( sorted( task_list.items() ) )
```

I want a total_task_list such that the "Overdue Tasks" is first in the sorted dictionary, followed by the dates in task_list in chronological order.

Comment: you can append one dict to the other.

Comment: What are you storing in `overdue_actions`?

Comment: @njzk2 that's the source of my question.  How to append one dict to another such that they are in a pre-specified order

Comment: @RaydelMiranda I'm storing a list of objects from a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django [SortedDict](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict) support `insert`. You can:

```
total_task_list = SortedDict( sorted( task_list.items() ) )
# And then:
total_task_list.insert(0, 'Overdue Tasks', [overdue_actions, 0])
```

this way you will have "Overdue Task" as first item in `total_task_list`.

Comment: Is there a way to insert this at the last?